# Django Translate Templates String Filter

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have read the [documentation](https://sodocumentation.net/django/topic/2579/internationalization) and a created a tag `<div>{{ site_name|default:_("It works!") }}</div>`. In order to translate the "It works!" string, I just configured the django.po file as shown bellow and the translation was successful:

```
msgid "It works!"
msgstr "Funciona!"
```

However, trying to translate the "No" string in the [index.html](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/geonode/templates/index.html#L129), I configured the django.po file as shown bellow and I got no translation:

```
msgid "No"
msgstr "Sem"
```

Would anyone point me if I missing any configuration for translating the "No" string in the index.html file.

Comment: `python src/manage.py compilemessages`?

Comment: @allexiusw, I run compilemessages every time I edit django.po file. But still not taking any effect for the "No" string.

Comment: I haven't used `_("mytext")` in templates, is that posible? Why you don't use `{% trans "mytext" %}`?  I don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: I think the problem may be related to string with several meaning like "May" (month and verb) as is shown here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers